# Update post (published) date when changing category

Tags: wp-update-post

Is there a way to update a post (published) date when you change the category/taxonomy to a specific one?

Example:
- Post type "Projects"
- 2 categories: Progress/ Done
When you change the category for the post "Project One" (from Progress) to Done, the published date has to be the currect date and time, zo it will be the last published post.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the date the post was last modified, using the Default date format setting (e.g. F j, Y) from Administration > Settings > General.
Here is a code using Default date formate.

```
<p><?php printf( __( 'Last modified: %s', 'textdomain' ), get_the_modified_date() ); ?></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. I also need to know if the category has been changed to "Done".

Comment: Any ideas on this case?

Comment: Please see [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/display-the-last-updated-date-of-your-posts-in-wordpress/).

Comment: Thanks, but not helping.. I CAN check which post was last updated && which post has the category "Done". Because I need to display the newest "Done Project". But what if you change an other post, just the content.. Than that post will appear as the newest. You understand?